# Privacy terminology: Online privacy vs Internet Privacy vs Digital Privacy

Tags: privacy, terminology, standards

While, to my eyes, Digital Privacy is the broader term ( anything digital whether online or not), I have seen all 3 used interchangeably (i.e: [link vs title](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/online-privacy)). Also, despite having different [entries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_privacy) in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_privacy), not much is clarified. 
 Looking at the number of hits, the far more common term seems to be online privacy, with the other two returning similar numbers.

So, is there any commonly accepted usage for this yet? Are the 3 terms simply synonyms?

Comment: Internet is antique, online is a classic, digital is in trends and you can wow people.

Comment: From your comment I understand that aside from sounding old-fashioned or trendy, either one could be used in a given sentence and the meaning would remain the exact same. Is that right? If so, a source would be much appreciated, this way you can turn the comment into an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: This is my view from an IT engineer's standpoint. If you browse archive.org and search for those specific terms you may come out with evidence.

Comment: Digital privacy can include things like hard drive and file encryption, which is neither online nor internet privacy. Internet privacy and online privacy are synonymous, with digital privacy being a superset of former two. There is also data/information privacy, which all of these fall under (e.g. information privacy would encompass physical documents, which is not related to digital privacy).